How check and switch login by multiple conditions
On the front-end app I have one login panel. From this panel I send email and password by API to back-end. Using Java 11, I want login one of three methods: user, worker or contact person. What should I do? How can I check who is logging in? If user then switches login method on user. If worker then switch methods on worker. If contact person then switch method on contact person.
This is my code but working only logInByUser. The rest is error NullPointerException.
Edited code:
During loggin user by email and password everything is good, I can log in to app. If I try log in by worker or contact person with email and passowrd I got NullPointerException. Sometimes I see logs in terminal but it's too quickly to see anything and an NullPointerException is immediately displayed.
When I write correct email then uzytkownikDao.isUserExist(request) return 1. When I write wrong email from User table or correct email from Worker table then if statement return NullPointerException but I expect return 1 from Worker table. It seems that it keeps trying to return only the first condition, not including the other else if conditions.
public Object handleLogin(@RequestBody RequestLoginDefault request) {
    if (uzytkownikDao.isUserExist(request) > 0) {
            return lonInByUser(request);
        } else if (pracownikDao.isWorkerExist(request) > 0) {
            return logInByWorker(request);
        } else if (osobaKontaktowaDao.isContactPersonExist(request) > 0) {
            return logInByPerson(request);
        } else return null;
}

public Long isUserExist(RequestLoginDefault request) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Long count = (Long) session.createQuery("select count(*) from User where email = :email and password = :password")
            .setParameter("email", request.getEmail())
            .setParameter("password", request.getPassword())
            .getSingleResult();
    return count;
}

public Long isWorkerExist(RequestLoginDefault request) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Long count = (Long) session.createQuery("select count(*) from Worker where email = :email and password = :password")
            .setParameter("email", request.getEmail())
            .setParameter("password", request.getPassword())
            .getSingleResult();
    return count;
}

public Long isContactPersonExist(RequestLoginDefault request) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Long count = (Long) session.createQuery("select count(*) from ContactPerson where email = :email and password = :password")
            .setParameter("email", request.getEmail())
            .setParameter("password", request.getPassword())
            .uniqueResult();
    return count;
}


From which line the NPE is triggered?

re-check your logic. try and understand why this: private boolean checkInUsersTable(RequestLoginDefault request) {
boolean isUserLogin = userDao.isUserExist(request);
return true;
} is nonsense-code

What do you suggest? What should I do?

@treumiton what does that method return?

I think it all will work if you remove return true statement in these methods and refactor to these
private boolean isUserLogin(RequestLoginDefault request) {
return userDao.isUserExist(request);
}
But it still will be the nonsense. so please recheck your code

isUserExist returned Integer: 1

@treumiton what does checkInUsersTable return if the User exists? What does that method return if that user does not exist?

I removed private boolean checkInUsersTable, checkInEmployeesTable and checkInContactPeopleTable. Now the code looks like this:
if (uzytkownikDao.isUserExist(request) > 0) {
            return lonInByUser(request);
        } else if (workerDao.isWorkerExist(request) > 0) {
            return logInByWorker(request);
        } else if (contactPersonDao.isContactPersonExist(request) > 0) {
            return lonInByPerson(request);
        }

Can anyone tell me exactly how I should correct the code to make it work? Maybe I should use something else instead of if satement?

I've been working on this for three days now and I really have no idea how to fix it

If statement check only the first isUserExist condition and it does not go to the rest and displays the NullPointerException error, I don't know why. I don't see System.out.println of the remaining two methods because is only java.lang.NullPointerException. Can anyone advise?

@treumiton 1) please [edit] your question to add (not replace) the modified code. 2) please tell us where exactly that NullPointerException happens.

I edited the code because question is closed.

@treumiton so what? You didn't need to replace what you already had. You could have added at the bottom of the question. And you still haven't clarified where the NullPointerException happens (considering that an if doesn't return anything, especially not an exception). Maybe consider adding the stack trace as well, maybe it could clarify what you mean.
